# Initial z-Index for Windows

Tags: qooxdoo

When I create a new modal window in qooxdoo it gets a z-index of 100000.
A second window will get a z-index of 100002. etc.

How can I set an initial value to 1000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic zIndex assignment is done by a `qx.ui.window.Manager` instance. See http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/pages/desktop/window_management.html

`qx.ui.window.Manager` has a private member `_minZIndex` which is initated with a value of 10000. In order to change that, you have to derive your own window manager class from `qx.ui.window.Manager` and change that value in the overridden constructor, like this:

```
qx.Class.define("qx.ui.window.MyManager",
{
  extend : qx.ui.window.Manager,

  construct : function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this._minZIndex = 1000;
  }
});
```

(Please change the class path `qx.ui.window.MyManager` to your needs).

You could then replace the window manager of your application by using the following code, before creating the first window. A good place would be at the beginning of the overridden `main` method of `qx.application.Standalone` in your application
(see: http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/api/#qx.application.AbstractGui~main):

```
var oldWindowManager = this.getRoot().getWindowManager();
var desktop = oldWindowManager.getDesktop();
var windowManager = new qx.ui.window.MyManager();
windowManager.setDesktop(desktop);
this.getRoot().setWindowManager(windowManager);
qx.ui.core.queue.Widget.remove(oldWindowManager);
oldWindowManager.dispose();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Unfortunately the function 

this.getRoot().setWindowManager(windowManager);


stucks. Firebug reports: TypeError: obj is null var clazz = obj.constructor;
Has it to do with an interface?

Comment: I've tested the code with Firefox which works without any problems. 

Did you create the derived window manager class within its own file `<approot>/myapp/source/class/ui/window/Manager.js` with a corresponding namespace in `qx.Class.define` like `maypp.ui.window.Manager`?

And did you run `./generate.py source` to test the source version or `./generate.py build` to test the build version?

Comment: @Raymond did you solve the problem? Please report back. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The window is a qx.ui.core.Widget. It inherits the zIndex property. So use setZIndex http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.core.Widget~setZIndex

Comment: This does not help, as the window manager dynamically assigns the zIndex, depending on how the windows are stacked an on their modality.